# Why sed regexp changes the text partially and inconsistently

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, sed

I wanted to change `"abc ö-Ö ä-Ä å-Å def"` string's ä to ae, å to aa and ö to oe.

```
sed -i 's/ä/ae/g' aFile | sed -i 's/å/aa/g' aFile | sed -i 's/ö/oe/g' aFile
```

This command sometimes changes only ö and ä and sometimes only ä. It is strange that the command sometimes works one  way other times other way. What is wrong with it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you provide (a significant portion of) the input file? also pls provide more information on what platform are you running this on, what are your locale settings..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-i` (edit in place) and pipelines don't mix. Either of the following two commands will work:

- `sed -i -e 's/ä/ae/g' -e 's/å/aa/g' -e 's/ö/oe/g' aFile`
- `sed -i 's/ä/ae/g' aFile; sed -i 's/å/aa/g' aFile; sed -i 's/ö/oe/g' aFile`

Basically, what's happening in the code as given in the question is that the three `sed`s are all started in parallel and they all want to modify the same file. This results in undetermined behavior, because you cannot possibly know which of the three `sed`s reads what from the file.

Secondarily, if `sed` is called with `-i` (edit in place) it does not read standard input and does not write standard output.

Ah and by the way this only takes care of lowercase `[äåö]`.

Comment: Thanks  @AlexP for your very helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the goal with single **sed** command:

```
sed -i 's/ä/ae/g; s/å/aa/g; s/ö/oe/g' aFile
```

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest! Actually I had solved the problem the way you wrote, but the behavior of sed was strange, so I posted the question ;)